# Can ReSharper ignore projects/tests in navigation

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.0

When using the various navigation and usage features of ReSharper, is there a way to make it hide some of the projects (with tests) in the solution?

Often when I'm browsing through the code, I'm not really interested in the tests, but only the production code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I received this answer from the Resharper support team.

> I have looked at "find usages" deeper and figured out that there is the
>   following item in filter dropdown -- "Show Unit Test Usages" (attached). So
>   if you uncheck this item -- usages from Test Projects won't appear in search
>   result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well im not sure this works for the navigation and usage features but for analysis it does, tryto use the skip files and folders menu to add folders which should be excluded.

Under Optionmenu use Settings under the Code Inspection section and select "Edit Items to Skip" and select your folder.

Take a look at this [Article](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/06/preventing-items-from-being-analyzed-in-resharper/) too

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no setting in ReSharper to "forget" a certain project in solution.

However, in some cases, navigation combos may help you out.

For example, when you search for types, files or symbols with ReSharper, you can restrict search scope with navigation combos. Say, in NHibernate, entering "`dm spec` " in Go to Type restricts search scope to `Projects\Core\NHibernate.DomainModel\NHSpecific`